# handler not running android

Tags: android, handler

i have a function To run messages in a queue. But when I run this the last handler gets executed only, not the first one! Help!

```
void functionShow()
    {

        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txt.setText("Generating Unique ID ... Please Wait ");

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                txt.setText("Sending SMS ... Please Wait");       
            } 
       }, 10000); 


        Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
            public void run()
            {
                txt.setText("Done");
            }
        }, 10000);



    }
```

All i am trying to do is: First text should come as "Generating Unique ID ... " Then after 10 secs "Sending SMS ... " Then again after 10 secs "Done"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both have the same delay... I guess the first one is being executed and a couple of milliseconds after that the second one is executed; so it looks like the second one is the only that is being executed.

The ugly way:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            txt.setText("Sending SMS ... Please Wait");
            postDelayed(new Runnable () {
                public void run(){
                    txt.setText("Done");
                }
            }, 10000);
        } 
    }, 10000);
```

The cool way:

```
private static final int SENDING = 1;
private static final int DONE = 2;
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch(msg.what){
            case SENDING:
                txt.setText("Sending SMS");
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(DONE, 10000);
                break;
            case DONE:
                txt.setText("Done");
                break;
        }
    }
};
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SENDING, 10000);
```

Comment: All i am trying to do is:
First text should come as "Generating Unique ID ... "

Then after 10 secs

"Sending SMS ... "

Then again after 10 secs

"Done"

Comment: Then, **OBVIOUSLY**, you are doing it in the wrong way... let me change my answer.

Comment: This ain't working .. But i found another way .. check my answer!

Comment: void functionShow()
    {

        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        txt.setText("Generating Unique ID ... Please Wait ");   


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                txt.setText("Sending SMS ... Please Wait");       
            } 
       }, 10000); 


        Handler handler1 = new Handler();
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
            public void run()
            {
                txt.setText("Done");
            }
        }, 15000);



    }